# Amazon Redshift: CTE or sub query for complex queries?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, amazon-redshift

For complex queries with multiple tables, which is the better approach? Common table expression or sub queries ?

Comment: IIRC redshift is based on a (stripped down?) pre-8.4 postgres version, so it does not *have* CTEs. Which makes the choice easier.

Comment: Redshift does support CTEs (with clause).  See the Redshift documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sub queries is much better than using Common table expression. The query analyzer will perform better when using multiple sub queries instead of common table expression.

Comment: I do not agree with this answer. I am a new Redshift user but I wrote two very simple queries one with CTE and one with a subquery. When I checked the explain plan for both it came out to be exactly same!

While it may make some differences in other DBS but in Redshift, it seems like both are evaluated same way by the compiler. So it is your personal choice of writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please note however, you are far better off with rewriting to an outer join than to use a correlated sub query.  As there are no indexes in Redshift, forcing a sub query for each row of data will result in a very costly O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation.

Comment: Simple sub-query doesn't use values from the outer query and is being calculated only once! So, It wouldn't end up with O(n2) operations..

Comment: Totally agree with you re:simple sub-queries.  The author didn't specify one way or the other (although as a comparison to CTEs, you are correct that simple sub-queries are implied).  Given the massive negative performance implication of _correlated_ sub-queries, I thought it prudent to highlight the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would say temporary tables. In temporary tables you can define the DIST KEYs and control the performance. CTEs might not perform that well